# Optimal Load Balancer Setup for Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, load-balancing

I've recently been tasked with load balancing a Meteor application and it seems to be quite an overhaul, mainly because of sticky-sessions and current load balancer support. I'd like to build one from scratch instead of using pre-cooked solutions such as ELB, Nodejitsu, or Modulus.

So far I've looked at HAProxy and Nginx which both seem to be viable options but these have been my issues:

HAProxy - The issue here is that sockjs seems to not be able to establish a reliable connection. This is most definitely to do with not supporting sticky sessions.

Nginx - Will only route to one of the servers in the config.

I've looked around and it seems that the optimal solution is a custom load balancer that basically assigns a server to a client to establish a connection with.

I'm hoping there is an existing solution out there using HAProxy or Nginx that will play nice with Meteor and the underlying WebSockets implementation.

Comment: MeteorHacks has a lot of great info that might give you some ideas. You can start here http://meteorhacks.com/how-to-scale-meteor.html

Comment: Better documentation for this will emerge as Meteor approaches 1.0. See the following bit in Meteor's Trello: https://trello.com/c/NVfdwled/74-document-how-to-build-a-scalable-ddp-proxy-tier

Comment: I have heard of people successfully using both HAProxy and Nginx in production.  HAProxy definitely supports sticky sessions.  Can you describe more of what problems you are seeing?

Comment: Absolutely, so when I deploy with HAProxy and connect with a client I receive a series of sockjs errors in the web console. Conversely with Nginx, it only makes requests to one load-balanced application server.

Comment: I use nginx. Here is my config: https://gist.github.com/dnprock/53fa74153d29557aa699. Although I still have issue with code reload. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769925/how-to-make-meteor-get-code-from-one-server-with-load-balancer

Comment: @PhuocDo
Is the latest ngix config have fix for code reload?

Becuase the answer says so

Comment: I don't think it is supported in their distribution. I had to compile my own sticky session.

Comment: Passenger allows Meteor to play nicely with Nginx https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/