# How to make meteor get code from one server with load balancer

Tags: javascript, cookies, nginx, meteor, load-balancing

I'm running nginx load balancer for meteor application. My app occasionally run into reload loop and does not terminate. I take some debug screenshots here:

https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B0ayFgn4x5Sccjd1QTdYdDNkNXc

In reload_route_cookies.png (see below), client side shows multiple cookie routes. How do I make sure that my app only loads code from one server?

[image]

Comment: I found that setting AUTOUPDATE_VERSION environment variable to constant can fix this issue. Although it disables hot code reload.

Comment: I think better to use a hardware load balancer with sticky bit so it stays on same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that telling nginx sticky session path=/ will fix the issue.

```
upstream vida_node_server {
    sticky path=/;
    # ...
}
```